# Click on a button to change Selected TabBar Item

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i'm trying to use a button to change the selected Item on a TabBar. I'm trying to use a method that is called when the button is clicked. The method is:

```
-(IBAction)vaiProdotti 
{
     [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
}
```

But when i click my app crash. I have only 2 items on my tabBar and i have created my project as TabBar app so i'm using that bar. Any hint?

SOLVED: I hadn't connected the class of the item in the tabbar with my class.

Comment: Maybe your outlets are not connected or what message do you get when it crashes?

Answer (score 1):

From Apple Docs:

> selectedIndex
>
> The index of the view controller associated with the
>   currently selected tab item.
>
> @property(nonatomic) NSUInteger selectedIndex
>
> Discussion
>
> This property nominally represents an index into the array of the viewControllers
>   property. However, if the selected view controller is currently the
>   More navigation controller, this property contains the value
>   NSNotFound. Setting this property changes the selected view controller
>   to the one at the designated index in the viewControllers array. To
>   select the More navigation controller itself, you must change the
>   value of the selectedViewController property instead.

Maybe you're trying to set the selectedIndex from a pushed viewController. Try printing the selectedIndex in the viewController where you wanna call the method and check if its right.